# Collapse two data frames into one where entries get concatenated

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames with identical row.names and colnames. However, the entries in each field vary between the two data.frames.

Like the following structure:

```
df1 = data.frame(SETD2 = c('AMP', NA, ''), PIK3CA = c('', 'AMP', 'AMP'))

row.names(df1) = c('Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3')

df2 = data.frame(SETD2 = c('', 'Nonstop', 'truncating'), PIK3CA = c('nonsense', 'InFrame', ''))

row.names(df2) = c('Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3')
```

I am simply looking for an easy solution to merge these two data frames into a single one, where the desired output just looks like

```
df3 = data.frame(SETD2 = c('AMP;', 'NA;NonStop', 'truncating'), PIK3CA = c('nonsense', 'AMP;InFrame', 'AMP;')
```

As you can see, just that the individual entries gets merged and separated by a
`';'`

Many many thanks,
chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These use only base R.

**1)** We first use `Map` to `paste` over the two data frames giving list `L` and then `replace` the `df1` entries to convert `L` to a data frame.

```
L <- Map(function(...) paste(..., sep = ";"), df1, df2)
replace(df1, TRUE, L)
```

Alternately replace the last line with this:

```
out <- df1
out[] <- L
```

or with this:

```
as.data.frame(L, row.names = rownames(df1))
```

In each case we get:

```
              SETD2      PIK3CA
Sample1        AMP;   ;nonsense
Sample2  NA;Nonstop AMP;InFrame
Sample3 ;truncating        AMP;
```

**2)** An alternative is to convert both `df1` and `df2` to matrices since they can be pasted in parallel.  We paste them together giving character vector `p` and then use `replace` or `out[]<-` as in (1).  This alternative does not use `Map` or similar.

```
p <- paste(as.matrix(df1), as.matrix(df2), sep = ";")
replace(df1, TRUE, p)
```

or replace the last line above with:

```
out <- df1
out[] <- p
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)
Most efficient method I can think of ~ works just perfect, however ```row.names()``` are not preserved ... 
But, can life with that :)
Thanks,
chir.

Comment: Have added variations.  All now set row names.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach which is close to what you want, using `paste0()` and `bind_rows()`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(id=row_number()),df2 %>% mutate(id=row_number())) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(SETD2=paste0(SETD2,collapse = ';'),
            PIK3CA=paste0(PIK3CA,collapse = ';')) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  SETD2       PIK3CA     
  <chr>       <chr>      
1 AMP;        ;nonsense  
2 NA;Nonstop  AMP;InFrame
3 ;truncating AMP;
```